# Remove CA2000 warning for object of collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code i have different object of collection.

I am getting CA2000 warning after running code analysis in VS2000.

I try to use microsoft way by using temporary object .
I also can not use using.

```
public static MetadataEntity GetStepMetadata(StepEntity stepEntity, string code)
    {

        StepMetadataCollection values = null;
        StepMetadataCollection tempvalues = null;
        try
        {
            values = new StepMetadataCollection();
            IPredicateExpression selectFilter = new PredicateExpression(StepMetadataFields.WfStepId == stepEntity.Id & StepMetadataFields.Code == code);

            values.GetMulti(selectFilter);
            tempvalues = values;
            values = null;

        }
        finally
        {
            if (values != null) {
                values.Dispose();
            }   

        }

        return  tempvalues;
    }
```

Comment: [CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx)

Comment: i try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx this but still its giving me same warning CA2000

Comment: It looks like you followed the pattern (except that you swapped the temp and non-temp variable names).  Are you sure it's complaining about `StepMetadataCollection`?  Is `PredicateExpression` possibly `IDisposable`?

Comment: it is for StepMetadataCollection CA2000 Warning:  call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'values' before all references to it are out of scope.